# Which roles should I include in production.rb while deploying a Rail API app using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-deployment, capistrano3

I have a Rails 5 API application and I want to deploy it on a remote server which hosts both application and database (Postgres).

I managed to deploy only after I removed `web` and `app` roles

```
server "myserver", user: "myuser", roles: %w{db}
```

When I add `web` or `app` the Capistrano fails to deploy. For example it tries to precompile assets or tries to find a folder which does not exist.

I understand that Capistrano lets us tag each server with one or more roles, so we can control what tasks are executed where.

How do we know exactly which role executes which task? In particular, what role(s) do I need to successfully deploy a Rails 5 API application?

I could not find any information on Capistrano home page answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

For a single server deployment, my Capistrano configuration typically looks like

```
# role-based syntax
role :app, %w{user@myserver}
role :web, %w{user@myserver}
role :db, %w{user@myserver}
```

So three `role` statements for the same server.

I guess Capistrano is executing different tasks depending on each role - e.g. migrations are run on `db`, asset compilation is run on `web` etc. So if you have a single server, it would take all roles.

If your deployment only works for some of the roles, that would be an indicator that your deployment process is not setup correctly.

Comment: In order to tell whether or not my deployment process is setup correctly I NEED TO KNOW which role (db, web, app) runs which tasks. I really know that db runs migration (since it is db related). I also deduce that web runs asset compilation after some trial (NOT LEARNING FROM DOCS). What tasks does app run? Any docs or reference?

Comment: In your question you say that you deploy to a single server. In that case you don't need to care about role - task relations.
The whole point of role configuration is only needed in case you have a more complex load-balanced setup with multiple servers for the same application.